GL2 action on torsion sections of elliptic curves
I am reading Kato's $p$-adic Hodge theory paper and I am confused about a rather embarrassing and admittedly very minor thing, but it is nevertheless important.
In Section 1.6 of Kato, it is claimed that $\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$ acts on a point $(E, e_{1}, e_{2})$ as follows: $\sigma$ sends $ (E,e_{1}, e_{2})$ to $ (E,e_{1}',e_{2}')$ where $$ \begin{pmatrix} e_{1}' \\ e_{2}' \end{pmatrix} = \sigma^{t} \begin{pmatrix} e_{1} \\ e_{2} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} e_{1} \\ e_{2} \end{pmatrix} . $$
I presume that the intended meaning here is $$ e_{1}' = a\, e_{1} + b\, e_{2} \\ e_{2}' = c\, e_{1} + d \, e_{2}. $$
Kato claims that this is a left action, but it seems to be a right action to me because of the transpose.
Later on in Section 1.1.4 of Takako-Kato, this transpose is gone, but we are not told whether this is a left action or right explicitly (it seems to be left).
Question 1. Is the transpose in Kato's p-adic Hodge paper intentional or a typo?
A related matter is as follows. I have come to prefer the convention of "right action on spaces, left action on cohomology" which seems to be the standard in arithmetic geometry field (see, e.g., Section 1.3 of this paper). As such, I like to view the modular curve at hand as $$ \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Q}) \backslash \mathbb{H}^{\pm} \times \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{A}_{f})/K(N)$$
where $ \mathbb{H}^{\pm} = \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R} $ and $K(N)$ is the adelic principle congruence subgroup of level $N$. The moduli interpretation given for instance in Milne would have me think that a point on the (disconnected) modular curve of principal level $N  \geq  3  $ are given by $(E,f)$ where $E$ is an elliptic curve and $$ f : (\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}/N\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})^{2} \to E[N] $$ is an isomorphism, where $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ denotes profinite integers (of course, the domain here is just $(\mathbb{Z}/N \mathbb{Z})^{2}$). Then $ g \in  \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$ would act on the modular curve by sending $ (E, f) $ to $ (E, f \circ g) $ where $ g $ acts on the left of $ \widehat{\mathbb{Z}} \oplus \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ in the usual way (i.e. if I write elements of $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} \oplus \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}   $ as column vectors, then $g$ acts by left matrix multiplication). This gives a right action on the modular curve. Let's unravel what this means in terms of a basis for $E[N]$. I have the following picture
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^{2} @>{f'}>> E[N]\\
@VV{g}V  @VVV\\
(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^{2} @>{f}>> E[N]
\end{CD}
where the right vertical arrow is equaltiy. The point $(E,f) $ can be viewed as $(E,e_{1},e_{2})$ by taking $$e_{1} = f\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad e_{2} = f\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$ Similarly we may view $ (E,f') $ as $ (E,e_{1}', e_{2}')$, and I'd like to pin down how $(E, e_{1}', e_{2}')$ is obtained from $ (E, e_{1}, e_{2}) $. Say $ g = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} $. The picture above tells me that $(E, e_{1}', e_{2}') $ is obtained from $ (E, e_{1}, e_{2}) $ via the following formula: $$ e_{1} ' = a \, e_{1} + c \, e_{2} \\ e_{2}' =  b\, e_{1} + d \,e_{2} $$
or equivalently in Kato's notation, $$ \begin{pmatrix} e_{1}' \\ e_{2}' \end{pmatrix}  = g^{t} \begin{pmatrix} e_{1} \\ e_{2} \end{pmatrix} $$
So at the end, I do have to put a transpose to obtain a right action. Some sources (e.g. see top of p.25 in this paper) put an inverse in this formula rather than a transpose, and I am a little confused which one is supposed to be the correct one (of if I am making some stupid mistake).
Question 2. To get a right action, should we put a transpose or inverse in the formula above?

I'm pretty sure that when Kato writes "$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix}$" in the second line of $\S$1.6, it is a typo, and it should say $\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$. So the transpose is not there, and Kato has a left action on the space, and hence a right action on the functinos.
For your more general question: both conventions (left vs. right action) exist in the literature; one is arguably more natural if you think of the modular curve in the classical way as $\Gamma \backslash \mathcal{H}$ (which seems to be Kato's preference), and the other if you think of it in more automorphic language as $GL_2^+(\mathbb{Q}) \backslash (\mathcal{H} \times GL_2(\mathbb{A}_f)) / K$. Worse, when one needs to translate between left and right actions, some sources use inverse and others use transpose. This leads to a recurring minor irritant of sign discrepancies between papers. It's a pain.
(As evidence for why this is the correct reading: look at Kato's definition of $Y(M, N)$ in section 2.1; in particular $Y(1, N)$ is the quotient of $Y(N)$ by $\begin{pmatrix} * & * \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, and he claims that this is exactly the quotient through which the map $(E, e_1, e_2) \mapsto e_2$ (forgetting $e_1$) factors. See the passage "The canonical morphism... represents...". So the action of $\begin{pmatrix} * & * \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ should fix $e_2$ while (maximally) muddling around $e_1$, implying that the transpose shouldn't be there.

Thanks a lot! I have a follow up. Could you explain how starting from the adelic description of modular curve (where one puts the compact open on the right) leads to the action by inverse of $g$ in modular interpretation? I am unable to derive this inverse version.

Perhaps the origin of the inverse sign is the choice of the non-standard Shimura datum? I can see how it affects Galois action but I am still unable to relate it the moduli interpretation.

On the other hand, I found one possible way to get this inverse action: define a left action $\mathrm{GL}_{2}(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}) \times (\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})^{2} \to (\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})^{2}$ by $(g, v) \mapsto (g^{t})^{-1} v$ (so $g$ acts by matrix multiplication on the column vector $v$ by transpose inverse). Then the argument sketched above returns the interpretation in your paper. But this seems a rather bizarre way of arriving at this inverse convention.

I think the root issue here is that the literature is not quite settled on what "the standard Shimura datum" is!

I agree. Maybe Kevin Buzzard in his lifetime will be able to help us through these $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ torsor issues, that have plagued the theory of Shimura varieties.
